# Functions Scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

In Pro JavaScript with Mootools book I have found the below line

```
The scoping rules for function expressions are a bit different from function 
declarations because they depend on variable scoping. Remember that in 
JavaScript, the var keyword defines a variable to be scoped locally, and 
omitting the keyword creates a global variable instead:
```

As per my understanding I have written the below code and tried to check this

```
var a = function(){ 
   b = function(){ c = function(){ alert("b"); }; };
};
alert(typeof a); // Returned me 'function'
alert(typeof b); // Returned me 'undefined'
alert(typeof c); // Returned me 'undefined'
```

And I also tried below

```
var a = function(){ 
   var b = function(){ c = function(){ alert("b"); }; };
};
alert(typeof a); // Returned me 'function'
alert(typeof b); // Returned me 'undefined'
alert(typeof c); // Returned me 'undefined'​​
```

Could you please explain this to make me understand better. As per my understanding in first block of code b and c should be global variables.. But this is not happening in this case. Even I tried to invoke `a()` before alerts... [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ4vK/) is the fiddle. Please help me on this to understand scope better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As per my understanding in first block of code b and c should be global variables

They are, but they won't have values assigned to them until `a` is called (and until `b` is called in the case of `c`).

> Here is the fiddle

That code is different. You have `var b`, which makes `b` a local variable and not a global.

---

```
var a = function(){ 
   b = function(){ c = function(){ alert("b"); }; };
};
a();
b();
alert(typeof a); 
alert(typeof b); 
alert(typeof c);
```

Comment: Please look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HJ4vK/5/ . In this case. `b` also becomes global variable right?

Comment: No, since you declare `var b` it is local to the containing block, which in this case is the function assigned to `var a`.

Comment: JavaScript does not have block scope. `var` makes things local to the closest function that contains them (which is still the one assigned to `a`).

Comment: @Quentin The closest function of `c` is `a` or `b`?

Comment: `a = function(){ b = function(){ c =` … which *looks* closer?

Answer (score -1):

Google the key word below, it is a good place to master scoping and other javascript pattern techniques. It is a series of articles with 12 parts. There are no direct links on the website so  you need search for the rest of the articles using part number

```
  search for
   
    elegant code basic javascript part 1
    elegant code basic javascript part 2
    etc...
```