# JavaScript variable with global scope

Tags: javascript, scope

This is an Extension to the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540329/functions-scope-in-javascript/11541574#11541574). I have tried below code to understand JavaScript scope

```
var a = function(){
   var aa = 10;
   var x = 13;            
   b = function(){ c = function(){ alert(aa); }; };       
};
a();
b();
c();
alert(typeof x);​ // Undefined
alert(x);​ // Returned me 13.
```

My query is I have declared variable with `var`​ inside a global function. As per my understanding `x` should be local. But it is not acting in that way. Someone please clear my doubt... Please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HJ4vK/6/) fiddle.

Comment: `x` is scoped to the function assigned to `a`. That last `alert` never  actually appears - you get a SyntaxError because `x` is not defined.

Comment: There is no way you will get 13, you will get 'x is not defined' because x is scoped inside a. Maybe you have set x = 13 somewhere in the global scope also.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MYbKT/ As @JamesAllardice said

Comment: There is no possible way that that alerts "13".

Comment: If you're testing your code in a developer console, you need to be sure to refresh the page to clear any previously set `x` globals.

Comment: @Pointy Please check http://jsfiddle.net/HJ4vK/6/

Comment: @SoI - The fiddle you are linking to is not alerting "13". It alerts "10" because you are alerting the value of `aa` inside the function assigned to `c`.

Comment: @SoI: Your fiddle shows the last alert as `undefined`. What's the trouble ?

Comment: Done. No 13, which in the case of that fiddle is even less surprising than for the code you posted, as the fiddle lacks the last `alert()` call.

Comment: Hi All, I am agreeing my mistake.. I misunderstood...

Comment: What might have been the case is that you forgot the `var` in front of the x which makes it a member of the global object.  In this case, the last alert would give you 13. However the `alert(typeof x)` would give you `"number"` then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will happen:

An alert popping up, displaying the value of `aa` = `10`

An alert popping up, saying `undefined` since you are trying to access a variable `x` from the global scope, however `x` is only defined in the scope of function a.

An error in your console, `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

So, as you assume, x indeed is private, you can't access it globally.

You probably messed something up giving you wrong results.

What might have been the case is that you forgot the var in front of the `x` which suddenly makes it a member of the global object instead of being restricted to the function-scope. In this case, the last alert would give you 13. However the alert(typeof x) would give you `"number"` then.